# shared_ptr and threads issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

The code I'm currently working on had it's own `RefPtr` implementation which was failing at random.

I suspect that this could be a classic data race. `RefPtr` has a pointer to original object that inherits from the `RefCounted` class. This class contains a reference counter (`m_refCount`) that is not atomic and an application was crashing inside some threadwork accessing object through `RefPtr` stuff. Just like the object under `RefPtr` got destroyed. Quite impossible.

The object instance that is held by `RefPtr` is also held by two other objects that do *not* modify it (or its contents) and I'm 100% sure that they have shared ownership of it (so `m_refCount` should never go below 2)

I did try to replace the pointer with `std::shared_ptr`, but the crash is still there.

The distilled code representing this issue:

```
class SharedObjectA
{
    public:
        int a;
}

class Owner
{
    public:
        shared_ptr<SharedObjectA> objectA;
}

class SecondOwner
{
    shared_ptr<SharedObjectA> objcectA;
    public:
        shared_ptr<SharedObjectA> GetSharedObject() { return objectA;}
        void SetSharedObject(shared_ptr<SharedObjectA>  objA) { objectA = objA;}
}

void doSomethingThatTakesTime(SecondOwnerA* owner)
{
    sleep(1000+rand()%1000);
        shared_ptr<SharedObjectA> anObject = owner->GetSharedObject();
        int value = anObject.a;
        std::cout << " says: " << value;
}

int main()
{
    Owner ownerA;
    ownerA.objectA.reset(new SharedObjectA());

    SecondOwner secondOwner;
    secondOwner.SetSharedObject(ownerA.objectA);

    //objectA instance

    while(true)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            std::thread tr(doSomethingThatTakesTime,secondOwner);
        }

        sleep(4*1000);
    }
}
```

What's happening is up to 4 threads access `SharedObject` using `GetSharedObject` and do something with it.

However, after giving it some time - the `use_count()` of `shared_ptr` will go down below 2 (it should not) and eventually below 1 so the `object(objectA)` will get destroyed.

**Edit**
Obviously there is no synchronization in this code. However i don't see how this could be related to the fact the use_count() getting below 2. the shared_ptr is guaranteed to be thread safe for the sake of reference counting, isn't it?

Comment: Please make a real reproducible example.  As is your loop that spawns the threads should either crash since the thread is destroyed without joining or detaching.

Comment: You program crashes because of thread not joined, not because of `shared_ptr`

Comment: this doesnot explain why use_count() gets below 2

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any kind of synchronization on access to the shared object. `shared_ptr` does not do any synchronization in access to the pointed-to object, it just ensures that the memory pointed to gets released after all references to it are destroyed.

You also need to `join()` your threads at some point.

Comment: How does that explain the share count going down?

Comment: Also? This is the reason of crash.

Comment: But this does not explain why shared_ptr.use_count() gets below 2. While accessing object under shared_ptr is not thread safe (and can't be guaranteed by shared_ptr) the reference counting should be - as such it should never get below 2 in my example